# Как правильно вызвать процесс из python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, macos

В общем, написал простой конвертер систем счисления. Хочу его автоматически протестировать скриптом. Использую `subprocess`.
Код `main.py`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

alpha = {i+10:chr(65+i) for i in range(0, 26)}

def from_to(from_, to_, number):
    temp = int(number, from_)
    #print('debug -> {}'.format(temp))
    digits = []
    while temp > 0:
      reminder = temp % to_
      if reminder > 9:
        digits.append(alpha[reminder])
      else:
        digits.append(reminder)
      temp //= to_
      #print('debug -> {}'.format(digits))
    res = []
    while len(digits):
      res.append(digits.pop())
    return ''.join(list(map(lambda x: str(x), res)))

def app():
  print('Hello! U can convert numbers!')
  from_ = 0
  to_ = 0
  number = 0
  while from_ not in range(2, 35) or to_ not in range(2, 35):  
    from_ = int(input('Choose base from convert to: '))
    to_ = int(input('Choose base for convert to: '))
    number = input('Enter number: ')
    result = from_to(from_, to_, number)
    print(result)
    break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

Код тестироващика `auto.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

data = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
  for i in f.readlines():
    data.append(i.split(','))

data = list(map(lambda x: [i.rstrip() for i in x], data))

# for i in data:
  # from_ = i[0]
  # to_ = i[1]
  # num_ = i[2]
  # ans_ = i[3]
p = subprocess.Popen(["./main.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate('2\n3\n10101\n')
print(out)
```

Когда запускаю `auto.py` почему-то вылетает такая ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./main.py", line 36, in 
>       app()
>     File "./main.py", line 28, in app
>       from_ = int(input('Choose base from convert to: '))
>   EOFError: EOF when reading a line
>   Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
>   BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Я уже пробовал и `stdin` менять и `stdout`, убирал цикл(который закомментирован), но в упор не замечаю что не так.

Comment: Потому что перед этим ваш `auto.py` выдаёт другую ошибку, которую вы вроде бы должны отлично видеть

Comment: @andreymal так дело в том, что сама программа работает, если запускать вручную из терминала.

Comment: Так я говорю про ошибку в auto.py, а не в main.py

Comment: Неужели никаких других текстов ошибок больше нет?

Comment: @andreymal в комментарии это всё, что есть (

Comment: @andreymal да и в auto.py ничего такого нет, просто файл читает и лист запоминает(

Comment: В auto.py «такое» очень даже есть, и об этом пишет текст ошибки на моём компьютере https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkTlh.png — очень странно, что у вас такого текста нет

Comment: @andreymal Понял, спасибо большое. Там и правда в этом была проблема. Жесть. Ещё собственно всё верно, я пока тестил и искал ошибку абсолютно точно установил, что проблема в stdin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен, что у Вас заработает этот вариант, но [документация](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) говорит, что входные данные должны быть переданы как массив байт:

```
out, err = p.communicate(b'2\n3\n10101\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Читал документацию и не заметил!

Comment: @kot_mapku3, рад, что помог Вам!